# How to convert React Content Loader to SVG?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I have created a content loader on **[Danilowoz](http://danilowoz.com/create-content-loader/)** and i want to convert it to **SVG**. I did research and visited countless websites to achieve this task but i am failed to do so.

How to convert React Content Loader source code to SVG?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a good question, but may I ask why / what's the use case?

Comment: I am working on android app. I want to use it there

Comment: You need to get the svg and animate it with android tools, you cant just export it as animated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Step 1

Create your loader:

```
import React from "react"
import ContentLoader from "react-content-loader"

const MyLoader = () => (
  <ContentLoader 
    height={160}
    width={400}
    speed={2}
    primaryColor="#f3f3f3"
    secondaryColor="#ecebeb"
  >
    <rect x="70" y="15" rx="4" ry="4" width="117" height="6" /> 
    <rect x="70" y="35" rx="3" ry="3" width="85" height="6" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="80" rx="3" ry="3" width="350" height="6" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="100" rx="3" ry="3" width="380" height="6" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="120" rx="3" ry="3" width="201" height="6" /> 
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
  </ContentLoader>
)

render(<MyLoader />)
```

#### Step 2

Create a SVG file (like `loader.svg`), [add `svg` element container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) and save it.

```
<svg>
  <rect x="70" y="15" rx="4" ry="4" width="117" height="6" />
  <rect x="70" y="35" rx="3" ry="3" width="85" height="6" />
  <rect x="0" y="80" rx="3" ry="3" width="350" height="6" />
  <rect x="0" y="100" rx="3" ry="3" width="380" height="6" />
  <rect x="0" y="120" rx="3" ry="3" width="201" height="6" />
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
</svg>
```

---

Now you got your SVG file, you even can drag and drop it to your favorite prototyping app like Figma/Zeplin etc:

[image]

Comment: It worked but not properly. Some design components are different from their actual size.

Comment: If you ever have seen static animated SVG I would very like to see it, you usually animate with CSS/js, also, thats NOT what you asked